# Android ListView not detecting selection

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm stumped. This one IS simple and I'm missing something simple but I'm just not getting anywhere.

I have a ListView that contains pretty simple items - TextView's that contain text of the form "N. name", where N is the position in the list and name is the name of the associated objects. I've created a ListAdapter that presents that information into the ListView.

The presentation stuff seems to work fine. It's the part where when I tap on a row that's not working. I just don't get a notification. If I set a onClickListener on the item (when it's generated in the Adapter) I do get a notification, but it's convoluted to make that work the way I'd like it to. I've tried a bunch of stuff - changing descendent focusability, enabling, disabling, setting itemsCanFocus to false, ... - but no luck on any of them.

I've included relevant code for configuring the view and the elements in the ListView.

In particular, what I'm trying to do is get that `OnItemClickLister.onItemClick()` to get invoked when I tap on a row. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    model = FZMModel.getInstance(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deploy);

    TextView viewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deploy_header);

    if (model.getProfiles().size() == 0) {
        viewTitle.setText(R.string.deploy_header_create);
    } else {
        viewTitle.setText(R.string.deploy_header_choose);
    }

    profileListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.profileListView);
    profileListAdapter = new ProfileListAdapter(this, model);
    profileListView.setAdapter(profileListAdapter);

    profileListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Item %d selected (with id=0x%x)", position, id));
        }
    });
}
```

Adapter:
... relevant code from getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Profile profile = model.getProfileAtIndex(position);
    final int rowNum = position;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView profileIndexView;
    TextView profileNameView;

    profileIndexView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileIndexLabel);
    profileNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileNameLabel);

    profileIndexView.setText(String.format("%d.", position));
    profileNameView.setText(profile.getName());

//     convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//         @Override
//         public void onClick(View view) {
//             Toast.makeText(context, String.format("Did select row #%d (index=%d)",rowNum, profile.getPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//         }
//     });
    return convertView;
}
```

activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nsn.flexizonemobile.FZMConcreteActionDeploy"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/deploy_header_choose"
        android:id="@+id/deploy_header"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileListView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deploy_header"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

profile_list_layout layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_index_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="A.         "
        android:id="@+id/profileIndexLabel"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Profile Name"
        android:id="@+id/profileNameLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileIndexLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please change choisemode="none" to singleChoice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the textview of your inflator layout just add:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and in parent layout of your inflator i.e in relative layout of inflator add:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

remove :

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

from your listview. and set height of your listview to match_parent will solve your issue.

Comment: This seemed to get it. I'm not sure I understand exactly how or why this works, but disabling the focusability of the list item views allows the listview to see the clicks. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I both up-voted and selected as the answer? Did I miss something? The up arrow is lit and the checkmark is there

Comment: @CubsFanRon the reason your OnItemClickLisener didn't work was that your TextView "consumed" the touch event (I assume it's the textIsSelectable attribute). Basically your TextView tells its parent, parents parent, etc: "don't bother, this click was meant for me" by removing focusability, your TextView won't misinterpret your click as "user wants to focus on me" and the the event can bubble up to its parent

Answer (score 1):

remove following attributes from your ListView:

```
android:choiceMode="none"
android:clickable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

also

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

makes no sense in this context (especially height)

Comment: didn't see android:textIsSelectable="true" in your row layouts, it might consumes the touch event ... you got to remove it